# Simple Jquery function syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make simple Jquery function like this:

```
function switchButton($param) {
 $param.on('change', function() {
  var result = $($param +'.switch-field input[name=switch]:checked').val();
  alert(result);
});
}
```

Execute like this:

```
switchButton(('.switch-field input'));
```

Please help to format this function correctly. Thank you.

Comment: `switchButton($('.switch-field input'));` missing the `$`.  And then your inner lookup would need to be changed to `$param.find('.switch-field input[name=switch]:checked').val()`

Comment: This is a _normal JavaScript function_; a jQuery function is attached to the jQuery prototype and called on jQuery objects like `$('input').val()`. Just be aware of the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/111367/

```
function switchButton(element) {
    element.on('click', function() {
        alert(element[0].id); // do something
    });
}

switchButton($('#btn1'));
switchButton($('#btn2'));
```

Comment: Ok, I will ask it differently, how to convert code below to proper function:

function switchButton() {
   $('.switch-field input').on('change', function() {
      var result = $('.switch-field input[name=switch]:checked').val();
      alert(result);
   });
}
So it can be used as easy as possible in different places.

Comment: @LifeIsShort - if you need to clarify your question, then Clarify your _Question_ ... don't try to shovel more code in comments.

Comment: What @StephenP said. Also, take the template code I gave you above and fork off that. Don't wait for someone to give you the exact code you need for your application just so you can copy paste it or you're going to have a rough time in software development.

Comment: @LifeIsShort Cheers.